# Java Case Insensitive Method Breakdown and Explanation

Tags: java, regex, string, syntax, case-insensitive

```
public class StringMatchesCaseInsensitive
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String stringToSearch = "Four score and seven years ago our fathers ...";

      // this won't work because the pattern is in upper-case
      System.out.println("Try 1: " + stringToSearch.matches(".*SEVEN.*"));

      // the magic (?i:X) syntax makes this search case-insensitive, so it returns true
      System.out.println("Try 2: " + stringToSearch.matches("(?i:.*SEVEN.*)"));
   }
}
```

The code block above is what it is; an example of a case-insensitive search. But what I'm most interested in is this : `"?i:.*SEVEN.*";`.

I know that `?:.` is the case-insensitive syntax. But what about the `.*` that encapsulates `SEVEN`? What does it do?

Where can I read more about the `.`, `*`, and `.*` regex modifiers?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is what those symbols stand for.

- `.` stands for any character except the newline. If used with `s` flag then it matches newline too.
- `*` is quantifier which says `zero or many`.
- `.*` will say `zero or many characters`.

You can read more about them on

- [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)
- [Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm)